# How to pass a JSON Object in HTTPURLConnection

Tags: json, playframework

I am using org.json.simple.JSONObject. I want to pass a JSONObject using HTTPURLConnection. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I converted JSONObject as a string and converted the string as JSONObject in the target. Atleast for now.

Comment: may i know how you did it

Comment: I couldn't exactly remember it, i hope this could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17651395/convert-jsonobject-to-string

Answer (score 1):

It's probably late for this answer but, just in case, I paste below the code I use for that goal:

```
URL url;
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
 try {
  url = new URL(SOME URL...);
  JSONObject reqJson = THE JSON OBJECT TO BE PASSED...;
  urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
  BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream()));
  bw.write(reqJson.toString());
  bw.flush();
  bw.close();

  //Now handle response
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
   ...
   ...

  } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
    urlConnection.disconnect();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the `play.libs.WS` class, and set this JSON object as a string to a specified parameter name.

Comment: I cannot use WS for some limitations