# Convert JsonObject to String

Tags: java, string

```js
{
    "data": 
    {
        "map":
        {
            "allowNestedValues": true,
            "create": "2012-12-11 15:16:13",
            "title": "test201212110004",
            "transitions": []
        }
    },
    "msg": "success",
    "code": "0"
}
```

Above is a `JsonObject`, the `data` is a `JsonObject`.

How to convert it to a `String` like `"msg":"success"` as you know, i can't directly add a double quotes outside `data`'s value.

Comment: I can't get it... Could you rephrase and give (even non-working) code snippets illustrating what you're attempting to do?

Comment: JsonObject.getString("msg");

Comment: You can add doublequotes with a backslash `\"` if that´s what you want. Please add your problem/question!

Comment: Is that an instance of `org.json.JSONObject`? If it is, you can simply call `toString()` method of `JSONObject` to get JSON text of the`JSONObject`.

Comment: It looks like what people who land here 3+ years later are finding useful is not at all related to what was asked. And it also looks like the question is long past help at getting clarified. I believe the original question was that @JayZhang wanted to flatten the object, such that data was a string representation of its inner json value. It seems no one answered how to do that. Doing so years later would be unlikely to have any value to others. People are landing from searching for converting json to a string and getting mired in a confused Q&A session best deleted.

Comment: It isn't just, as @dlamblin pointed out, that people are "landing" here years later, it's that the question really didn't have a lot to do with JSON in the first place. Yes, it does appear the OP wanted to know how to "flatten" the contents of "msg", but that gets into all sorts of questions about quoting quotes and "how does the OP expect to parse this thing and turn it back into something useful." There are some built-in string transforms, but with the OP's silence, who knows which one would have been most appropriate.

Comment: Which library is this JSONObject from ?

Answer (score 215):

There is a built-in method to convert a `JSONObject` to a `String`. Why don't you use that:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

json.toString();
```

Comment: {
    "data":
  "{ "map": {
                "allowNestedValues": true,
                "pdId": 168543,
                "source": ""
            }
     }",
     "msg": "success",
    "code": "0"
}

Comment: i'm getting \ \ \ slashes in response string. how to convert json object without getting \ \ \ slashes

Comment: @Onkar share your string sample along with code snippet.

Comment: similar to this thread. but unable to find answer. https://stackoverflow.com/q/16563579/8098322

Comment: {"date":"2013/5/15"}. Are u using import org.json.JSONObject;
its working fine for me. Share your exact sample.                                                   JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    try {
    json.put("date", "2013/5/15");
   } catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
     System.out.println(json.toString());

Comment: Is this the same for Java EE's JsonObject?

Answer (score 25):

You can use:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.toString();
```

And if you want to get a specific value, you can use:

```
jsonObject.getString("msg");
```

or Integer value

```
jsonObject.getInt("codeNum");
```

For long Integers

```
jsonObject.getLong("longNum");
```

Comment: It is better to use jsonObject.optString("msg") and jsonObject.optInt("codeNum") because if you use getString() or getInt() and the msg or codeNum values are null it'll throw and error and stop the program. Only difference with the methods I have mentioned is they won't  throw an error if the values are null.

Answer (score 9):

you can use

```
JsonObject.getString("msg");
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try Gson convertor, to get the exact conversion like json.stringify

```
val jsonString:String = jsonObject.toString()
val gson:Gson = GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create()
val json:JsonElement = gson.fromJson(jsonString,JsonElement.class)
val jsonInString:String= gson.toJson(json)
println(jsonInString)
```

Answer (score 4):

JsonObject seems to be JSON-P API. If this is true, I would use JsonWritter to write JsonValue into StringWriter:

```
    JsonObjectBuilder pokemonBuilder = Json.createObjectBuilder();
    pokemonBuilder.add("name", "Pikachu");
    pokemonBuilder.add("type", "electric");
    pokemonBuilder.add("cp", 827);
    pokemonBuilder.add("evolve", true);
    JsonObject pokemon = pokemonBuilder.build();
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(128);
    try (JsonWriter jw = Json.createWriter(sw)) {
        jw.write(pokemon);
    }
    String pokemonStr = sw.toString();
```

Answer (score 3):

Add a double quotes outside the brackets and replace double quotes inside the `{}` with `\"`

So: `"{\"data\":{..... }"`

Answer (score 2):

Use This :

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
JSONObject.valueToString(json.toString());
```

Comment: `JsonObject` =/= `JSONObject`

Answer (score 1):

Example of Model

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String age;
// setter and getter
// toString method
}
```

Example of Service method

```
public String getPerson() {
        JSONObject returnObj = new JSONObject();
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setAge("24");
        person.setName("Fazal");
        returnObj.put("age", person.getAge());
        returnObj.put("name", person.getName());
        return returnObj.toString();
    }
```

Json in java dependency needed

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>{New_Version}</version>
</dependency>
```

You will get this type of JSON result
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject metadata = (JSONObject) data.get("map"); //for example
String jsonString = metadata.**toJSONString()**;
```

Comment: JSONObject json= (JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(jsonData);                                   JSONObject  data = (JSONObject)  json.get("data");                                       After you have parsed the json data, you need to access the data object      later get "map" data to json string.

Answer (score 0):

just use ObjectMapper

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS,false);
//here more config opts...
Car car = new Car("yellow", "renault");
objectMapper.writeValue(new File("target/car.json"), car);
String carAsString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(car);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject data = (JSONObject) data.get("map"); 
 //for example
String jsonString = data.toJSONString();
```

Answer (score -2):

```
     This should get all the values from the above JsonObject  
     System.out.println(jsonObj.get("msg"));
     System.out.println(jsonObj.get("code"));

     JsonObject obj= jsonObj.get("data").getAsJsonObject().get("map").getAsJsonObject();
     System.out.println(obj.get("allowNestedValues"));
     System.out.println(obj.get("create"));
     System.out.println(obj.get("title"));
     System.out.println(obj.get("transitions"));
```

Comment: this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score -2):

You can use reliable library GSON

```
private static final Type DATA_TYPE_JSON = 
        new TypeToken<JSONObject>() {}.getType();           
JSONObject orderJSON = new JSONObject();
orderJSON.put("noOfLayers", "2");
orderJSON.put("baseMaterial", "mat");
System.out.println("JSON == "+orderJSON.toString());
String dataAsJson = new Gson().toJson(orderJSON, DATA_TYPE_JSON);
System.out.println("Value of dataAsJson == "+dataAsJson.toString());
String data = new Gson().toJson(dataAsJson);
System.out.println("Value of jsonString == "+data.toString());
```

Answer (score -5):

```
 var data= {"data": {"map":{"allowNestedValues": true,"create": "2012-12-11 15:16:13","title": "test201212110004","transitions": []}},"msg": "success","code": "0"}
```

o/p:

```
Object {data: Object, msg: "success", code: "0"}
```

**Use JSON.stringify to convert entire data into string** like below

```
var stringData = JSON.stringify(data);
```

o/p:

```
"{"data":{"map":{"allowNestedValues":true,"create":"2012-12-11 15:16:13","title":"test201212110004","transitions":[]}},"msg":"success","code":"0"}"
```

**Use JSON.parse to convert entire string object into JSON Object** like below

```
var orgdata = JSON.parse(stringData);
```

o/p:

```
Object {data: Object, msg: "success", code: "0"}
```

Answer (score -7):

I think you need this :

> Suppose you have Sample `JSON` like this :

```
{"ParamOne":"InnerParamOne":"InnerParamOneValue","InnerParamTwo":"InnerParamTwoValue","InnerParamThree":"InnerParamThreeValue","InnerParamFour":"InnerParamFourValue","InnerParamFive":"InnerParamFiveValue"}}
```

> Converted to String :

```
String response = {\"ParamOne\":{\"InnerParamOne\":\"InnerParamOneValue\",\"InnerParamTwo\":\"InnerParamTwoValue\",\"InnerParamThree\":\"InnerParamThreeValue\",\"InnerParamFour\":\"InnerParamFourValue\",\"InnerParamFive\":\"InnerParamFiveValue\"}} ;
```

**Just replace " by \"**