# Does JsonObject have a stringify / toStyledString / or other to turn JsonObject to a String?

Tags: java, json

I was looking up the JsonObject class in Java: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html

I was trying to figure out how to take an object which I created and return it as a string.  See below:

```
public String toJson ()
  {
  JsonObject data = Json.createObjectBuilder();
  //this._myMap is just the private map variable defined: <String, FooClass>
  for ( Entry<String, FooClass> tuple : this._myMap.entrySet() )
    {
    data.add(type.getKey(), tuple.getValue().toString());
    }
  data.build();
  // String out = ...?
  return "-1";
  }
```

after first glance of the documentation, there isnt a toStyledString, or anything which would return a string, so i was curious as to how to approach it.   Im thinking that i could just do something with `Json.createWriter` or equivalent, but was not sure.

Comment: Did you try using `toString()`? From the docs, it seems `JsonValue` overrides this method

Comment: i did not try it.  I didnt not read that from the docs.  I will have to get back to you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert JsonObject to String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17651395/convert-jsonobject-to-string)

Comment: Wait, that uses:  JSONObject, whereas i am using JsonObject.   Is that justifible as "the same" for the purposes of keeping this open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `toString` was overriden, and when looking at the defintion of that function implementation, it states at: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonValue.html#toString()

> toString
>
> String toString()
>
> Returns JSON text for this JSON value.
>
> Overrides: toString in class Object
>
> Returns: JSON text