# How to generate JsonArray correctly?

Tags: java, android, json, web-services, android-studio

I am developing a java application in android studio and a Rest web server in java, netbeans.

I need to send a JSON to the server ... 
I did the whole engine the webService and tested it using Postman.

The Json used was this:

```
{
    "id":0,
    "ticket":"2132158645161654561651616",
    "avaliacoes":[
        {
        "idAvaliacao":1,
        "nota":5,
        "observacao":"testeTEste"
        },
        {
        "idAvaliacao":2,
        "nota":4,
        "observacao":"testeTEste"
        }
    ]
}
```

Worked perfectly.

So I went to generate Json dynamically in the application:

```
public void enviaDadosVenda(){
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray avaliacoes = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject avaliacao;

        try {
            obj.put("id", 0);
            obj.put("ticket", PrincipalActivity.ticket_id);

            for(int i=0; i < PrincipalActivity.listAval.size();i++){
                avaliacao = new JSONObject();
                avaliacao.put("idAvaliacao", listAval.get(i).getId());
                avaliacao.put("nota", listAval.get(i).getNota());
                avaliacao.put("observacao", listAval.get(i).getObservacoes());
                avaliacoes.add(avaliacao);

            }

            obj.put("avaliacoes", avaliacoes);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

The generated Json is this:

```
{
    "id":0,
    "ticket":"2132158645161654561651616",
    "avaliacoes":"[
        {
            \"idAvaliacao\":1,
            \"nota\":5,
            \"observacao\":\"testeTEste\"
        },
        {
            \"idAvaliacao\":2,
            \"nota\":4,\"observacao\":\"testeTEste\"
        }
    ]"
}
```

If I use this second Json on Postman the webService no gets it correctly.

Get the id and the ticket, but the evaluations array gets a single item(avaliacoes.get(0)) = null.

I've looked at other posts about Json and ArrayJsons and nothing helped me ...

[Parsing JSON Object in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015844/parsing-json-object-in-java)

[Convert JsonObject to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17651395/convert-jsonobject-to-string/17651567)

[How to create correct JSONArray in Java using JSONObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18983185/how-to-create-correct-jsonarray-in-java-using-jsonobject/51612613)

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/140442/reconhecer-um-jsonobject-ou-jsonarray

Comment: Use Gson Library to generate json.

Comment: Is this referencing `org.json.JSONArray` from Android? If so, would it not be `avaliacoes.put(avaliacao);` instead of `.add`? It appears your JSONArray is being treated as a String (instead of the correct org.json.JSONArray) and be serialized improperly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `avaliacoes.add(avaliacao);` with `avaliacoes.put(avaliacao);`

```
public void enviaDadosVenda(){
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray avaliacoes = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject avaliacao;

        try {
            obj.put("id", 0);
            obj.put("ticket", "DemoActivity.ticket_id");

            for(int i=0; i < 2;i++){
                avaliacao = new JSONObject();
                avaliacao.put("idAvaliacao", "1");
                avaliacao.put("nota", "nota");
                avaliacao.put("observacao", "observacao");
                avaliacoes.put(avaliacao);

            }
            obj.put("avaliacoes", avaliacoes);
            Log.d("DEMO", obj.toString());  // {"id":0,"ticket":"DemoActivity.ticket_id","avaliacoes":[{"idAvaliacao":"1","nota":"nota","observacao":"observacao"},{"idAvaliacao":"1","nota":"nota","observacao":"observacao"}]}

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

For best practice use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)