# How to Pass JsonObject in HttpURLConnection in android? When Used POST Method?

Tags: android, androidhttpclient

Suppose my link and parameters are such as

```
url :https/example.com/folder/something
parameters  : JsonObject. such as
{
    "foldername" : "imageFolder",
    "jsonArray"  : ["abc","sdsf","sfsd"],
    "location"   : "Dhaka"
}
```

How to send `JsonObject` using `POST` method via url in Android? Please help me anybody.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass a JSON Object in HTTPURLConnection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803006/how-to-pass-a-json-object-in-httpurlconnection)

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [HttpURLConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) already has an example of how to POST data to a server. I've elaborated on it a little to show creation of the JSONObject and writing the data to the OutputStream.

```
try {
    // Create parameters JSONObject
    String[] jsonArray = new String[] { "abc", "sdsf", "sfsd" };
    JSONObject parameters = new JSONObject();
    parameters.put("foldername", "imageFolder");
    parameters.put("jsonArray", new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(jsonArray)));
    parameters.put("location", "Dhaka");

    // Open connection to URL and perform POST request.
    URL url = new URL("https://example.com/folder/something");
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true); // Set Http method to POST
    urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0); // Use default chunk size

    // Write serialized JSON data to output stream.
    OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8"));
    writer.write(parameters.toString());

    // Close streams and disconnect.
    writer.close();
    out.close();
    urlConnection.disconnect();

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```